# tem como de fazer verificação neste arquivo?

Tags: php

```
<?php 

$ponteiro = fopen("nome.txt","r");

//LÊ O ARQUIVO ATÉ 
while (!feof ($ponteiro)) {
  //LÊ UMA
  $linha = fgets($ponteiro, 4096);
  echo "<b>".$linha."<br>";
}//FECHA WHILE

//FECHA
fclose ($ponteiro);
?>
```

queria saber se existe alguma forma para fazer uma verificação no arquivo txt se nele existe linha "1" ou nome "dast" e jogar no banco de dados

Comment: Coloque exemplos das várias linhas que pretende encontrar no seu arquivo

Answer (score 1):

Veja se é isso:

```
<?php
$termo = "dast";
$ponteiro = fopen("nome.txt", "r");
$linha = fgets($ponteiro, 4096);
if(strpos($linha,$termo) !== false){
    echo "Econtrado";
}else{
    echo "Não existe";
}
fclose ($ponteiro);
?>
```

---

Porém se você quer fazer um DB com arquivos eu aconselho a aprender JSON, a busca seria mais precisa.

Comment: E se o arquivo possuir alguns GB de tamanho? Consegue visualizar o que aconteceria no seu código?

Comment: GB de TXT, imagine inicialmente pra gerar o arquivo? O correto mesmo é usar o DB (MySql) pra que possa gerenciar com segurança, mas ele provavelmente que isso pra algum teste ou sub-sistema que ele está planejando ou criando.

Comment: Comentei isso pois acho válido deixar explícito que a sua solução não é viável quando o arquivo é muito grande, pois armazena o conteúdo inteiro em memória. Se o objetivo for analizar um arquivo de log, por exemplo, facilmente passa dos MB e isso poderia deixar o programa extremamente lento. O ideal seria, assim como no código da pergunta, ler o arquivo por partes.

Comment: Você tem toda razão, eu editei o código.